# onChange function not called with radio button and ReactJs hooks

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, react-hooks

> cl state is not updating. onChange method is not getting called ??
>   what is wrong??
>   sorry for image I am not able to get rid of format error in stackoverflow.

[image: radio buttton]

Comment: even a custom function is not called when calling from onChange in radio button.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Have you installed some plugin to convert class to className as class is a reserved word, so if you haven't installed any then change class to className.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet shows that it does work as expected. Only styling was removed.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [cl, setCl] = useState('');
  console.log(cl)

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="test"
          value="FEW"
          checked={cl === 'FEW'}
          onChange={() => setCl("FEW")}
        />
        FEW
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="test"
          value="SCT"
          checked={cl === 'SCT'}
          onChange={() => setCl("SCT")}
        />
        SCT
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it was due data-toggle attribute.

Comment: @Aashu This is why we require text or runnable snippets in questions, it would have been easier to find an issue like that, but instead I had to rewrite everything from the image and missed a part.

Comment: I am very sorry. I am new to the stackoverflow I was getting format error.could not get over that.so posted pic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the data-toggle attribute. I removed it and it started working.